# Matching two files and printing lines that appear first time

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two files that look like this:

file1 (unique IDs):

```
    C84610112
    C96209347
    C84774620
    C84774691
    C85594749
    C89372772
    C89651687
    C89845500
    C89914896
    C91269765
    C91526663
    C92210411
    C92254517
    C93709504
    C94303303
    C95100561
    C95100609
    C95417520
    C95696352
    C96045246
    C96045496
    C96060727
    C96076986
```

and file2:

```
    1  C95696352 score:  -69.785 nathvy =  38 nconfs =          888
    2  C98230482 score:  -57.431 nathvy =  47 nconfs =          575
    3  C96209347 score:  -57.128 nathvy =  24 nconfs =         1188
    4  C36510773 score:  -56.502 nathvy =  38 nconfs =         7595
    5  C04355288 score:  -56.400 nathvy =  41 nconfs =        50502
    6  C89372772 score:  -55.728 nathvy =  22 nconfs =         3228
    7  C96209347 score:  -54.713 nathvy =  24 nconfs =          162
    8  C96209347 score:  -53.901 nathvy =  24 nconfs =          159
    9  C06169346 score:  -53.438 nathvy =  22 nconfs =          105
   10  C95696352 score:  -52.848 nathvy =  38 nconfs =          878
   11  C98216318 score:  -52.061 nathvy =  52 nconfs =         1092
   12  C04285713 score:  -52.009 nathvy =  38 nconfs =         1355
   13  C96209347 score:  -51.477 nathvy =  24 nconfs =         1375
   14  C98222837 score:  -50.730 nathvy =  34 nconfs =          588
   15  C98216318 score:  -50.694 nathvy =  52 nconfs =         1136
   16  C32832068 score:  -50.546 nathvy =  22 nconfs =          548
   17  C95696352 score:  -50.475 nathvy =  38 nconfs =         3220
   18  C32832068 score:  -50.457 nathvy =  22 nconfs =        16235
   19  C95696352 score:  -50.234 nathvy =  38 nconfs =         3048
   20  C85594749 score:  -49.780 nathvy =  44 nconfs =         4536
   21  C72332782 score:  -49.676 nathvy =  41 nconfs =         3942
   22  C97970648 score:  -49.616 nathvy =  45 nconfs =        17640
   23  C04285713 score:  -49.594 nathvy =  38 nconfs =        14038
   24  C98043133 score:  -49.370 nathvy =  43 nconfs =         1236
   25  C89372772 score:  -49.308 nathvy =  22 nconfs =          471
   26  C97970648 score:  -49.297 nathvy =  45 nconfs =        17850
   27  C85594749 score:  -49.122 nathvy =  44 nconfs =         4158
   28  C70006381 score:  -49.092 nathvy =  24 nconfs =          880
```

I would like to match IDs from `file1` with IDs in `file2` (second column) and for those that are matching to print them. Also, in `file2` some IDs are repeating, such as `C96209347` (although whole lines are not identical). I would like to grep those lines that are appearing for the first time only and others to skip. So in this specific example with `C96209347` only third line from `file2` should be printed. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
grep -f file1 file2 | awk '!_[$2]++'

 1  C95696352 score:  -69.785 nathvy =  38 nconfs =          888
 3  C96209347 score:  -57.128 nathvy =  24 nconfs =         1188
 6  C89372772 score:  -55.728 nathvy =  22 nconfs =         3228
20  C85594749 score:  -49.780 nathvy =  44 nconfs =         4536
```

Explanation

- `grep -f file1 file2`: search in file2 for matches of patterns obtained from file1
- `awk '!_[$2]++'`: Don't print anything if field `$2` has been seen before ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916188/7365127))

  - `_` is the array name (can be anything, e.g. "seen")
  - `_[$2]++` will create an array entry with the key being the content of field `$2` and add 1
  - If `_[$2]` was **not** (`!`) already set, print the line. The `print`command is the default action that is made by awk when the condition matches.

Comment: Wow, nice and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

With awk alone:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=1; next} $2 in a {print; delete a[$2]}' file1 file2
    1  C95696352 score:  -69.785 nathvy =  38 nconfs =          888
    3  C96209347 score:  -57.128 nathvy =  24 nconfs =         1188
    6  C89372772 score:  -55.728 nathvy =  22 nconfs =         3228
   20  C85594749 score:  -49.780 nathvy =  44 nconfs =         4536
```